# git checkout to latest commit on current branch

Tags: git, version-control

I try to find a way to checkout to the latest commit in the current branch of a repository. I think this is trivial, I just can't come up with the right incarnation of commands.

To describe my problem a bit more in detail. This is what I want to achive. I want to automatically update the working directory of a git repository with the latest version from server but keeping whatever branch the repository is on right now and I don't care about local changes.

So first I run *git fetch* to get all commits from server.
Then I would do *git checkout HEAD* to advance to the latest commit or even *git chekout -f HEAD* since I don't care about local changes. Unfortunately this tells me:

> Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be
>   fast-forwarded.   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

But I do not want a pull since that would merge with local changes imho.
A *git reset --hard* also does not work since it would not advance to the latest commit. And a *git chechout master* also does not work since I don't know if this repository is on branch master or a different one.

So I think the command I am looking for would be something like this:

git checkout -f `git show_lastest_commit_on_current_branch`

P.s.:

While writing this I think I came up with a solution. First run a *git reset --hard* to throw away any local changes and then I can safely run *git pull* since there is nothing more which could create a conflict.
Is this the right thing to do?

Comment: `git fetch <remote> <branch> && git reset FETCH_HEAD --hard`.  But it's not a good practice unless you know what it exactly does.

Comment: @Fabian Your proposed solution, `git reset --hard && git pull`, would work if you don't have local commits. `git reset --hard` will get rid of staged or unstaged local changes, but will not remove any local commits you may have. Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: @HBHB yes that's what I want. I really only want to update the source of a server. So there won't be any branches on the server. Sometime I might have a local change like "Debug=True" in a config file which I want to get rid during this update. Right now the answer with "git reset --hard @{u}" looks awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably would not do this in the first place.  I'm not sure what your setup is, but in general, if there's anything that `git reset --hard` would obliterate, no automated script should be doing that at all.  If you want to have automated deployment, the deployment area probably should not be using Git this way in the first place.  (That is, “don't use Git at all” or “use Git, but treat the entire deployed branch as ‘build artifacts’ that are not source-controlled” would be the rule here.)

That said, if I *had* to do this, I'd probably go for [the method ElpieKay outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972599/git-checkout-to-latest-commit-on-current-branch#comment67224502_39972599), or something equivalent, such as `git fetch && git reset --hard @{u}`.

#### Finding the current branch

Note that if you want to get the *name* of the current branch, there are two ways to do this in a shell (sh or bash) script:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD) || exit
branch=${branch#refs/heads/}
```

Now `$branch` is, e.g., `master` or `deploy` or whatever.  If the repository is in "detached HEAD" mode, the call to `git symbolic-ref HEAD` printed:

```
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

to standard error, and then the `|| exit` clause made the script quit.  (Adjust behavior as desired by changing the script; add `-q` to suppress Git's message to stderr.)

Alternatively:

```
ref=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

Now `$ref` is, e.g., `master` or `deploy` or whatever, unless the repository is in "detached HEAD" mode, in which case `$ref` is the literal string `HEAD`.  (This is why I used the name `ref` rather than `branch`.)

#### Using `@{u}`

The `@{u}` syntax is short for `@{upstream}` and is described in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  In General, any place where Git needs a particular commit ID, you may spell it with any number of revision specifications.  A branch name like `master` simply translates to the tip commit on that branch.  Adding `@{upstream}` directs Git to:

- find the current branch (much as we did above);
- look up `branch.$branch.remote`, e.g., `branch.master.remote` is probably `origin`
- look up `branch.$branch.merge`, e.g., `branch.master.merge` is probably `refs/heads/master`
- combine the two lookup-results and apply the mapping rules in `remote.remote.fetch`, e.g., `remote.origin.fetch` is probably `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
- use the mapping output as a symbolic name for the appropriate remote-tracking branch, e.g., `refs/remotes/origin/master` is the full spelling for `origin/master`

Thus, `git reset --hard @{u}` "means" `git reset --hard origin/master` if you're on branch `master` and your local `master` is set to track remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.<sup>1</sup>  Note that because `@{u}` looks up the current branch, it fails immediately if you are in "detached HEAD" mode: a detached HEAD is not a named branch<sup>2</sup> and hence cannot be tracking anything.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are too many occurrences of the words "branch" and "track" in this, but that's how Git spells it out: a local branch (by name, such as `master`) is allowed to *track* one other branch.  The other branch that it tracks is usually a *remote-tracking branch* such as `origin/master`.  So:

1. `master` is a branch (or more precisely, a *branch name*);
2. `master`-the-name *tracks* something;
3. the thing it tracks is another name;
4. the other name is `refs/remotes/origin/master`, or `origin/master` for short; and
5. `origin/master` is a *remote-tracking branch*.

When the local branch named *B* is tracking a remote-tracking branch *RB*, the remote in question, and/or that branch on that remote, is what we (and Git) call the *upstream*.

<sup>2</sup>In fact, a detached HEAD behaves just like a branch, except that it has no name—or, for some purposes, it has the name `HEAD`.  You cannot set `branch.HEAD.remote` and `branch.HEAD.merge`, though.

---

#### The difference between `git fetch origin` and `git fetch origin master`

Assume we've set `$branch` as above.  Let's also set up `$remote` from `branch.$branch.remote`:

```
remote=$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote) || \
    die "branch $branch has no remote"
```

(where `die` does the obvious thing).

We are interested in the difference between these two alternatives:

```
git fetch $remote $branch && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD  # alternative 1
git fetch && git reset --hard @{u}                        # alternative 2
```

If your Git is not older than version 1.8.4, there is only one difference here: adding `$remote $branch`—let's say this is `origin master` for discussion purposes—tells your Git to bring over only the updates that go into your `origin/master`, rather than updating all of your remote-tracking branches.

That is, `git fetch origin` gets you *all* the updates from remote `origin`, while `git fetch origin master` gets you *only* the updates to their `master`.  If there are other updates to other branches, you skip them for now.  (You may have to pay the cost to get them later, and/or any such costs are typically tiny enough not to matter anyway.)

If your Git version is very old, though, there is one more difference: specifically, Git versions predating 1.8.4 fail to update `origin/master`, putting the new information *only* in the special `FETCH_HEAD` file.  (The `FETCH_HEAD` file is mainly meant for the `git pull` script to use.  It records, for `git pull`'s purposes, everything that `git fetch` brought over.  Remember that `git pull` simply runs `git fetch` first, then runs `git merge` unless you direct it to run `git rebase` instead.  The merge-or-rebase step uses the information saved in `FETCH_HEAD` to know how to do the merge-or-rebase.)

Which one should you use?  That's up to you.  Alternative 1 avoids fetching extra branches but requires setting up variables `$branch` and `$remote`.  This in turn forces you to decide up front what to do if you're not on any branch (if you're in detached HEAD mode).  Alternative 2 is easier to write, and simply fails automatically if you're in detached HEAD mode.  Alternative 2 updates *all* your remote-tracking branches (both good and bad, considering the extra work in fetching) and papers over the difference between Git 1.7 (pre-1.8.4) and Git 2.10 (post-1.8.3).  Papering over this difference is either neutral or good.

The `@{upstream}` syntax itself was new in Git version 1.7.  As far as I know, even the oldest-and-worst Linux distributions come with Git version 1.7.1 now, so there is probably no need to worry about someone still using 1.5 or 1.6.

#### Note that `reset` handles upstream rebases

Any attempt to use `git pull`, which runs `git merge`, can cause you trouble if your upstream does a rebase, or strips out commits.  This is because your remote-tracking branch (`origin/master` or whatever) is moving in a way that does not simply add new commits.  When that happens, Git will generally consider commits on *your* branch (your `master`) to be commits that *you* made, that they *never* had.  The `git merge` step will merge "your" commits with their latest, effectively *resurrecting* commits your upstream thought they had sent down the [memory hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hole).

If your upstream never does this, it is not a problem.

Comment: Awesome really a great summary and exactly what I needed!